# Dart sum list of lists by element

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add all elements in a list of lists by index and average them:

```
List<List<double>> data = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 3.0, 5.0], [8.0, 7.0, 2.0]]
```

The result should be a list of doubles each summed up and then divided by the total lengths of above data:

```
[11.0, 12.0, 10.0] // divide these by 3
[3.67, 4.0, 3.33] // should be the result
```

What is the best way to do this? This is taking too long in my flutter app (actual data list contains 60 lists of 2000 doubles each) and yes, I am also asserting the length of each list is equal. and is not empty or having unexpected data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My contribution for a Matrix NxM, I've modified your data for a more generic solution:

```
extension chesu<T> on List<List<T>> {
  List<List<T>> transpose() {
    final rowNum = this.length;
    final colNum = this[0].length;
    var list = List<List<T>>.generate(colNum, (i) => List<T>());

    if (rowNum == 0 || colNum == 0) return null;

    for (var r = 0; r < rowNum; r++)
      for (var c = 0; c < colNum; c++) list[c].add(this[r][c]);
    return list;
  }
}

main(List<String> args) {
  final data = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0], [6.0, 7.0, 7.0, 9.0]];
  print(data.transpose().map((e) => e.reduce((v, e) => v+e)).map((e) => e/3));
}
```

Result:

```
(3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 7.0)
```

There is a new package named [scidart](https://pub.dev/packages/scidart/) that contains interesting functions like `transpose`, it tries to emulate `numpy` from Python.

**UPDATE 1: Working with Big Data**

**UPDATE 2:** I made a fool mistake with `sum()`, `extension` is fixed now, sorry.

```
import 'dart:math';

extension on List<List<double>> {
  List<List<double>> transpose() {
    final rowNum = this.length;
    final colNum = this[0].length;
    var list = List<List<double>>.generate(colNum, (i) => List<double>());

    if (rowNum == 0 || colNum == 0) return null;

    for (var r = 0; r < rowNum; r++)
      for (var c = 0; c < colNum; c++) list[c].add(this[r][c]);
    return list;
  }
  
  List<double> sum() => this.map((l) => l.reduce((v, e) => v+e)).toList();
}


class Stats {
  List<List<double>> _data;
  int _rows, _cols;
  List<double> _sum, _avg;

  Stats(List<List<double>> data) {
    _data = data.transpose();
    _rows = _data.length;
    _cols = _data[0].length;
  }

  int get rows => _rows;
  int get cols => _cols;

  List<double> get sum {
    if ([0, null].contains(_sum)) _sum = _data.sum();
    return _sum;
  }

  List<double> get avg {
    if ([0, null].contains(_avg)) _avg = sum.map((e) => e / _cols).toList();
    return _avg;
  }
}


main(List<String> args) {
  // final data = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0, 5.0, 8.0], [6.0, 7.0, 7.0, 9.0]];
  // final data = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 3.0, 5.0], [8.0, 7.0, 2.0]];
  final data = List<List<double>>.generate(60, (i) => List<double>.generate(2000, (j) => Random().nextDouble()*30));
  print('Creating big data...');
  final stats = Stats(data);

  final stopwatch = Stopwatch()..start();
  print('Calculating statistics...');
  print('Sum: ${stats.sum.take(5)}');
  print('Average: ${stats.avg.take(5)}');
  stopwatch.stop();
  print('\nJob finished at ${stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds/1000} seconds.');
}
```

Result:

```
Creating big data...
Calculating statistics...
Sum: (928.8075263386316, 934.3418807027017, 815.2172548417801, 833.6855783984151, 828.1013228547513)
Average: (15.480125438977193, 15.572364678378362, 13.586954247363002, 13.894759639973586, 13.801688714245854)

Job finished at 0.024 seconds.
```

Comment: Hey mate, some problem with your stats. It just took about 2-3 seconds on my phone and on dartpad. This is the the best, most comprehensive answer. Thanks a ton for the exmaple of calculating these stats too.

Comment: I made a fool mistake with sum(), extension is fixed now, sorry.

Comment: That's amazing performance on Dart. Python takes quite a long time, even in it's most optimized version. Around 4 seconds to be precise. In any case, thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Well I really don't know about the speed you need.

Try this method to see if it works for your dataset. Maybe your method is faster!

```
void main() {
  List<List<double>> data = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 3.0, 5.0], [8.0, 7.0, 2.0]];
  List<double> dataSum = List<double>();
  
  // original data
  print(data);
  
  for (var item in data){
    dataSum.add(item.fold(0, (p, c) => p + c) / item.length);
  }
  
  // output
  print(dataSum);
}
```

**Important:**
Anyways, if you do a large task in time, you can use a `async` function with a `Future` to prevent the application to hang and not suffer because of the long wait.

---

*UPDATE: After OP's comment*

This code should give you the result you are expecting.

```
void main() {
  List<List<double>> data = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 3.0, 5.0], [8.0, 7.0, 2.0]];

  int numLists = data.length;
  int numElements = data[0].length;
  double sum;
  List<double> dataSum = List<double>();
  
  for(var i = 0; i < numElements; i++ ) { 
    sum = 0.0;
    for(var j = 0; j < numLists; j++ ) { 
      sum += data[j][i]; //inverted indexes
    }
    dataSum.add(sum/numLists);
  }
  
  // output
  print(dataSum);
}
```

Comment: Code looks good mate, thanks. But the result given by it is wrong:
```[2, 3.3333333333333335, 5.666666666666667]```, when it should be ```[3.67, 4.0, 3.33]```

Comment: (1+2+8)/3 = 3.67 should be the first element

Answer (score 2):

For operations on list you have to iterate over it's items (for, map, forEach ...etc) which would take time (depending on the list length) so I guess you have to do some benchmarking.

Try this

```
  List<double> sum = [];
  List<double> average = [];

  sum = data.reduce((a, b) {
    List<double> list = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      list.add(a[i] + b[i]);
    }
    return list;
  });

  average = sum.map((e) => e / 3).toList();

  print(sum);
  print(average);
```

Comment: Very fast result, takes about 2 seconds, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest more compact solution:

```
List<List<double>> data = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [2.0, 3.0, 5.0], [8.0, 7.0, 2.0]]

var result = <double>[];
final innerListSize = data[0].length;
for (int i = 0; i < innerListSize; i++) {
  result.add(data.map((e) => e[i]).average);
}
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.